# Linear dependence in a mixed effects model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have been building a linear model, but ran into a wall when including two variables which are identical and therefore linearly related. 
This has happened because one order of the experiment has only occurred at one site, which means I can't estimate a coefficient for the interaction of Site and order.

I was wondering if this is still a problem when running a mixed effects model. That is, include Site as a fixed effect and order as a random effect.

If I run this model in R using `lme4`,

```
y ~ Site + (1|Order)
```

I don't get any errors or warnings. But maybe this is something more abstract that a computer would tell me.

Please let me know if more information is required.

**EDIT**

The experiment consists of a series of tasks, conducted in one of 3 orders. This is represented in the example above as Order. The experiment was also performed on numerous sites, represented as Site. The result of the experiment is a score ranging from 1 to 7, this is represented as Y. 
My main interest is in whether Site affects Y. But, one of the orders only occurs in one of the sites. For example, Order C was only performed at Site X, and no other orders were performed at Site X, making the binary variable for Order C and Site X identical.

Comment: Please explain the experiment design and what each of the variables are.

Comment: @RobertLong I edited the question

Comment: Haven't thought about this *too* carefully, but it would probably be better to construct the `Site*Order` interaction by hand (paste the levels together, or use `interaction()`), make sure the unused levels are dropped, and fit that interaction as a single factor.